# Macro/inline-function workaround for missing uniform initializers in MSVC10/11

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

Is there a semi-transparent way that would make it easier to code in a style similar to what one would do with uniform initializers, without using the actual feature?

I'm willing to give up the type safety and other constraints of uniform initializers (I'll check their validity with other compilers), but I don't want to give up nice statements like

```
return { "foo", "bar" };
set<string> my_strings = { string_a, string_b };
```

A macro turning these into the compatible code for non-uniform initializer capable compilers would be of great use to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. The best you can do is [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/), but that only works for actual containers. And it doesn't look that nice.

If you're stuck with Visual Studio, you'll just have to live with it's C++11 support.